# HttpURLConnection Get Connection

Tags: java, android, get, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to create get connection but when i read header on server i found request Method received as POST not GET

[image]

Comment: so change it toPOST?

Comment: What are you even asking

Comment: i want it to be get and i'm sending from android get but i receive it on server post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing this line: `connection.setDoOutput(true);`

It may make the urlconnection think that you want to put parameters in the body and that you're trying to do a post